# Bundle node.js apps to a single file with Browserify

Tags: node.js, browserify

I'd like to distribute my node.js app as a single js file. The application is really simple, but it depends on a few libraries.

Browserify seems to bundle the `npm` dependencies nicely. However the app also depends on the `fs` built-in file system library and unfortunately its signatures doesn't seem to be loaded. For instance the following code gives `undefined is not a function` error.

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
```

I understand that main purpose of Browserify is to bring CommonJs based apps to the browser. But I wonder if there is any way to make the compiler fall back to the default `require` global function for built-in libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After going through all [options](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) it turned out that the `--bare` switch satisfies my requirement.

```
browserify --bare
```

Comment: I suggest using `--node` as its alias for both `--bare` and `--no-browser-field`.